# How can I add loading view at Launching time?

Tags: ios, launch

I'm using storyboard to develop my app, and the initial view controller is a Tab Bar Controller. At the AppDelegate I did some thing work to get the jsonData from my website. It will take 10-20 seconds . You know, I want to do something to notice user is loading, not just showing a default.png picture. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can have your `rootViewController` have a loading state (maybe an `UIActivityIndicatorView` on top of the other views and some public methods like `showLoading` and `hideLoading`.

Steps :

1. In the AppDelegate `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, build your rootView controller as usual and call your method that loads the JSON files.
2. Call the `showLoading` method when you're starting the request
3. Call the `hideLoading` method when you receive the response.

Also, remember to use asynchronous request or make it in a different thread to prevent blocking the main thread.